# How to design a nested polymorphism in OOP?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, polymorphism

Let's assume we have a simple payment feature on an online shop. We want to manage different transactions with different processors of transactions:

- A transaction can be a payment or a refund.
- A processor of transactions can be Paypal or Payplug.

So we have the following classes:

```
class PaymentTransaction implements Transaction {

}

class RefundTransaction implements Transaction {

}

class PaypalProcessor implements Processor {

}

class PayplugProcessor implements Processor {

}
```

What should be a good understanding of OOP?

1. `Processor.process(transaction);`
   or
2. `Transaction.process(processor);`

For example, if we take the example 1, how to avoid the following `switch` statement?

```
class PaypalProcessor {

    function process(Transaction transaction) {
        switch(transaction.getType()) {
            case payment:
            //..
                break;
            case refund:
            //..
  }
}
```

In all cases, how to manage a "nested" polymorphism, a strategy or something else to be able to manage the different transactions with the different processors?

PS: if the title is not appropriate, tell me I will edit it.

Comment: What you call 'nested' polymorphism can be solved with a mechanism known as double dispatch.  Double dispatch is used to polymorphically call methods based on not only the receiver of the call, but also the other arguments.  Some languages support multiple dispatch (or multimethods), meaning a function is able to be called polymorphically based on *all* of the concrete subtypes of its arguments.

Comment: @Kwadz You have two answers to your question. Please do comment on them for further clarifications.

Comment: @CKing Don't worry, I am perfectly aware about SO rules and habits. Even if your answer will probably be the accepted one, I just need to find the time to analyze each detail given here, especially what "double dispatch" is.

Comment: @jrahhali Do you know if we can implement _double dispatch_ in PHP?

Comment: @Kwadz Yes, you can.  Look up double dispatch on wikipedia to get some examples of implementing it in single-dispatch languages (most OOP ones).  The 'visitor pattern' is one implementation of double dispatch.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be on the right track. What you need is a third class for performing the operations (sample code in Java for the sake of discussion) :

```
class PaymentProcessor { 
     private Processor processor;
     private Transaction transaction;

     public PaymentProcessor(Processor processor, Transaction transaction) {
          this.processor = processor;
          this.transaction = transaction;
     }

     public void processPayment() {
         processor.process(transaction);
     }
 }
```

You can then *inject* the appropriate implementation of `Processor` and `Transaction` into the `PaymentProcessor` :

```
PaymentProcessor paymentProcessor = new PaymentProcessor(new PayPalDepositProcess(),new PaypalDepositTransaction());
PaymentProcessor refundProcessor = new PaymentProcessor(new PayPalRefundProcess(),new PayPalRefundTransaction());
```

Notice how you're `PaymentProcessor` can be passed different combinations of a *Processor* and *Transaction* without the need to have a *switch* statement.

Note that  `processor.process(transaction);` sounds more intuitive than `transaction.process(processor)`. Also note that you can consider using the  *Abstract Factory* pattern here since you seem to be creating a family of related objects (different types of processors that process different types of transactions)

Comment: I do not see how _Abstract Factory_ could match with this example. As explained in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern#UML_class_diagram), _Abstract Factory_ can be used when the factories have a theme in common. In other words, when creation methods of concrete factories extends ones of abstract factory. How would you consider it in this example?

Comment: Or may be I should rather ask: is an abstract factory with only one method still a valid abstract factory pattern?

Comment: @Kwadz Yes it is. I would have taken the efforts to explain how it fits in this example but not only is it out of the scope of this question, it is also a lot of efforts which may not reap any benefits seeing how long this answer has been left unattened. I was pointing you in the right direction by showing you how to reduce your conditional statements. Explaining how to adapt it to your example should ideally be a new post/question.

Comment: As suggested, I posted it as [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41943402/1941316).

Comment: In your example, where should be located the algorithms of the different cases of my switch statement? The different processors (Paypal, Payplug) are well supported but how to manage a payment, a refund?

Comment: Could you explain what is the worth added in your answer? As most of programming languages doesn't support _multimethods_, the `switch` statement is still needed.

Comment: @Kwadz See edit. And yes, you will need a *Switch* statement if you want to wire your objects at runtime rather than compile time. That said, I don't really have the interest left to continue answering further on this topic as explaining anything in comments is a huge pain and I see no merit in it in this particular case. You have already unaccepted the answer, you can also go ahead and downvote it and call it a day. Cheers.

Comment: By focusing on the patterns we forgot the most important. Please don't be irritated because I commented lately, I couldn't do it before. I unaccepted the answer because as I accepted it too quickly (your comments suggested a quick reply), I wasn't able to realize that it doesn't match actually with my question in his current state.

Answer (score 1):

I would make transaction object responsible for both processing payment and refunds.

```
interface Transaction
{

    public function pay();

    public function refund();
}
```

Then you'd have concrete ones like this:

```
class PaypalTransaction implements Transaction
{

    public function pay()
    {
        //process payment in a paypale way
    }

    public function refund()
    {
        //process refund in a paypale way
    }

}

class PayplugTransaction implements Transaction
{

    public function pay()
    {
        //process payment the way Payplug do
    }

    public function refund()
    {
        //process refund the way Payplug do
    }

}
```

Client code that would process transaction payment might look like this:

```
$customer = new Customer();

//concrete factory producing an abstract product (transaction)
$transaction = $customer->prepareTransaction('100 USD'); 

//process payment
$transaction->pay();

//in a similar fashion you would go about processing a refund
$transaction->refund();
```

Notice how the client code is kept in the dark about the concrete way money is transferred (implementation details, paypal or payplug). In other words the client is processing transactions polymorphically because it is coded to an abstract rather than a concrete object.

Customer in this example is the concrete factory for the client code:

```
class Customer implements Shopper
{

    /**
     * @param string $amount
     * @return Transaction
     */
    public function prepareTransaction($amount)
    {
       //use either paypal or payplug depending on the customer's preference 
    }

}
```

if the client was coded in a way it expects to work with an abstract object (e.g. "Shopper") then we'd have an appearance of an Abstract Factory pattern.

```
interface Shopper
{

    /**
     * @param string $amount
     * @return Transaction
     */
    public function prepareTransaction($amount);
}
```